# jackson mini json to object class

Tags: json, jackson

I was added "jackson-mini-1.9.2.jar"(is not "jackson-all-1.9.2.jar") in my project,
I want to convert json to object class.

Use "jackson-all-1.9.2.jar",we can use "ObjectMapper" to get it.
but use "jackson-mini-1.9.2.jar",How to do it?

If I write the follow code"

```
    String json = "{\"name\" : {\"first\" : \"Joe\", \"last\" : \"Sixpack\" }, \"gender\" : \"MALE\",   \"verified\" : false,   \"userImage\" : \"Rm9vYmFyIQ==\" }";
    JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
    JsonParser jp = f.createJsonParser(json);

    User user = jp.readValueAs(User.class);
```

The result is like that:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ObjectCodec defined for the parser, can not deserialize JSON into Java objects
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser.readValueAs(Unknown Source)
    at TestJackson.main(TestJackson.java:21)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement your own [ObjectCodec](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/ObjectCodec.html) and then register it with the JsonFactory by calling `JsonFactory#setCodec(myCodec)`.

Or (much easier!), just get hold of jackson-mapper-1.9.2.jar and add it to your classpath, so that you can use the default `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: Is it mean that:jackson-mini is not contain the function "json to object class",we should create our class extends ObjectCodec,to implements it, which looks like ObjectMapper in jackson-all.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Jackson-mini contains only the classes from jackson-core. This does NOT include ObjectMapper.

Comment: Thank you so~~~ Much!Good~~~ Luck!

Comment: My God!"jackson-mini" + "jackson-mapper" didn't work!java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.util.TokenBuffer;"jackson-core-asl" + "jackson-mapper-asl" can work,if there's other way to make it's size smaller?

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. The `TokenBuffer` class seems to be missing from jackson-mini. This looks like a packaging mistake. I guess you will have to use jackson-core + jackson-mapper.

Comment: Jackson mini is defined as the minimal useful subset if you DO NOT NEED data-binding; aimed at resource constrained use cases. TokenBuffer was left out on purpose, since it's a sizable class -- if you do need data-binding, use regular jars.
In a way this is a packaging challenge though: TokenBuffer should be part of mapper package, not core package; for Jackson 2.0 this can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use data-binding, do NOT use mini jar. It is only meant as the smallest possible jar to use Streaming Parsing (JsonParser, JsonGenerator).